# How to Vb.net XML Loop

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, loops

guys how i can loop the xml information using vb.net for insert in to database?

i try some few codec but the loop is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ComputerInformations>
  <ComputerInformation>
    <CompName>TESTUSER</CompName>
    <CompModel>OptiPlex 990</CompModel>
    <CompDomain>dnsx.local</CompDomain>
    <CompSystemType>x64-based PC</CompSystemType>
</ComputerInformation>
<ComputerMemoryInformations>
    <ComputerMemoryInformation>
        <CompMemBank>BANK 1</CompMemBank>
        <CompMemCapacity>2GB</CompMemCapacity>
        <CompMemManufacturer>Hynix/Hyundai</CompMemManufacturer>
        <CompMemPartNumber>HMT125U7BFR8C-G7</CompMemPartNumber>
        <CompMemSerialNumber>1B73E64A</CompMemSerialNumber>
        <CompMemSpeed>1067</CompMemSpeed>
        <CompMemBank>BANK 2</CompMemBank>
        <CompMemCapacity>2GB</CompMemCapacity>
        <CompMemManufacturer>Hynix/Hyundai</CompMemManufacturer>
        <CompMemPartNumber>HMT125U7BFR8C-G7</CompMemPartNumber>
        <CompMemSerialNumber>1BB3E65E</CompMemSerialNumber>
        <CompMemSpeed>1067</CompMemSpeed>
    </ComputerMemoryInformation>
  </ComputerMemoryInformations>
</ComputerInformations>
```

this is my vb.net Codec i am using vb.net 2015:

```
Function ParseXmltoDatabase(ByVal XmlData As String)
      Dim sr As New System.IO.StringReader(XmlData)
      Dim reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(sr)
      reader.MoveToContent()
      Dim inputXml = XDocument.ReadFrom(reader)
      Dim XmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(inputXml.ToString)
      Dim Xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
      Xdoc.LoadXml(XmlDoc.ToString)
      For Each node As XmlNode In Xdoc.SelectNodes("/ComputerInformations/ComputerMemoryInformations/ComputerMemoryInformation")
        Dim ComputerMemoryInformation As XmlElement = TryCast(node, XmlElement)
        Dim CompMemBank As XmlElement = DirectCast(ComputerMemoryInformation.SelectSingleNode("CompMemBank"), XmlElement)
        If CompMemBank IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("CompMemBank: {0}", CompMemBank.InnerText)
        End If
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

the problem is only i get the first result CompMemBank the Each is not working

Comment: You XML is malformed so badly we can't guess what it should be. Fix that and ask again.

Comment: Thanks correct XML added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too much code...all you need is this to iterate through those nodes:

```
Sub ParseXmltoDatabase(ByVal XmlData As String)
    With New XmlDocument()
        .LoadXml(XmlData)
        For Each node As XmlNode In .SelectNodes("/ComputerInformations/ComputerMemoryInformations/ComputerMemoryInformation/*")
            Debug.Print(node.Name & vbTab & node.InnerText)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Part of your problem was the XPath missing the `/*` at the end.